# Where does FactoryGirl save db entries in a Rails API app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm currently creating my first API only rails app.

What I'm struggling to get my head around is where exactly are entries being stored in the test environment? In a full rails app FactoryGirl would store entries in the _test database and passed to the controller - tested via something like RSpec.

I understand that in a rails API app you're foregoing the use of databases and instead aiming to store data in JSON format on a server - but in the case where I'm writing request specs, where is the information being stored/retrieved from? There is no server (locally or remotely) to hold the data!?

Apologies for my newbie question!

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just the format you use to make the communication from the client and the server, and backward, happen. But data are stored in a database as well. This is a spec I wrote in a rails api project to save a category (it's a request spec).

```
context 'everything is ok' do
  it 'gets a successfull response' do
    params = { category: category }.to_json
    post "/categories", headers: headers.merge("X-Api-Key" => partner.token), params: params

    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(json['success']).to be true
    expect(json['category']['name']).to eq 'Programming Languages'
  end
end
```

Just to give you an idea, I'm not pro at testing, I'm learning as well.

Answer (score 0):

> and instead aiming to store data in JSON format on a server

Nope. That would be silly. Rails API app is a regular rails app (with a database and whatnot). Only it does waaaay less html view rendering (ERB and such). That's the main difference.